# A detailed basic-level explanation of equations of lines and planes in 3-d geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors

I've searched multiple blogs but couldn't find anything helpful for my level. (I'm in the 12th grade learning about vectors in maths).

I basically need some thorough explanations regarding plane and line equations in 3 dimensions. I have a lot of unanswered questions which i'm hoping someone will answer!

PS: Please don't use any high-level mathematical notation or anything; I get very confused as i'm a newbie to the entire concept.

So here's what I know/don't know: (My questions are in **bold**.)

I know that the equation of a line in 2-d is something of the form *ax + by = c*. (**1. What is this form of a line called?**)

Similarly, I know that the equation of a plane is of the form *ax + by + cz = d*. I know that for all x-, y- and z-coordinates of a point on the plane, *ax + by +cz* will give d. However, I was also told that planes are referred to in terms of their normals. **So how to express a plane in terms of the normal to the plane?**

These are all the questions that come to mind for now; but I may end up having more.

Thanks in advance for being patient and explaining to a beginner!

Comment: **Question 1:** The equation $ax+by=c$ is called the *general form*.

Comment: **Question 2:** The equation that you have, namely $ax+by+cz=d$ already gives you what you want. The normal to the plane is the vector $a,b,c$.

Comment: [About lines.](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Calculus/StraightLine.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

$ ax + by = c $ or equivalently $ ax + by -c = 0 $ are usually referred to as an *implicit equation* or *general* (or *standard*) *form* for a line in $ \mathbb R^2 $ (the corresponding *explicit* equation or *slope-intercept form* would be either $ y =  -\frac{a}{b}x + \frac{c}{b} $, if $ b \ne 0 $, or $ x = \frac{c}{a} $ in case $ b = 0 $, that is, for a vertical line).

A line may be regarded as the locus of points satisfying the above *linear equation* in 2 dimensions. Likewise, the locus of points satisfying the linear equation in 3 dimensions $ ax + by + cz = d $ is a plane in $ \mathbb R^3 $.

If you have a line in $ \mathbb R^3 $, there is a whole family of planes having that line as a normal (just shift the planes along the direction of the line without changing their orientation in space). 
Up to a translation, we may therefore restrict our attention to planes passing through the origin and normal lines passing through the origin.

In this case, a point whose Cartesian coordinates are $ (x\ y\ z) $ will belong to the plane if and only if
$$ ax + by + cz = 0 $$
(with $ d = 0 $). This may be read as the ordinary scalar product between vectors $ (x\ y\ z) $ and $ (a\ b\ c) $; two vectors whose scalar product is zero are perpendicular. Therefore, the point whose coordinates are $ (a\ b\ c) $ must lie by definition on the normal to the plane. Since the line is through the origin, any other point on that line is found by multiplying $ (a\ b\ c) $ by any real number.

Vice-versa, if you have a line whose direction is specified by the vector $ (a\ b\ c) $, the plane through the origin having that line as a normal is specified by the equation $ ax + by + cz = 0 $.